# Accessing struct list on Start() gives NullReferenceError

Tags: unity-game-engine

What in the name of god am I doing wrong here? Every time I run the game I get this: "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object". I know what that means I just don't get why it is saying that?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour {

    public static Inventory instance;

    public List<InventoryItems> INVENTORY_ITEMS = new List<InventoryItems>();

    void Awake(){
        instance = this;
    }

    void Start(){
        Debug.Log(instance.INVENTORY_ITEMS); // ERROR
        Debug.Log(INVENTORY_ITEMS); // ERROR
    }
}

[Serializable]
public struct InventoryItems
{
    public string name;
}
```

Comment: Could be related to the serialization process with generic that is not optimal in Unity. Instead try to explicitly create the list in the Start.

Comment: What version of Unity are you on?

Comment: What line is the error on?

Answer (score 2):

This is how you should write this code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour {

    public static Inventory instance;

    public List<InventoryItems> INVENTORY_ITEMS;//do not initialize here

    void Awake(){
        instance = this;
        INVENTORY_ITEMS = new List<InventoryItems>();//init here instead
    }

    void Start(){
        Debug.Log(instance.INVENTORY_ITEMS); //no ERROR
        Debug.Log(INVENTORY_ITEMS); //no ERROR
    }
}

[Serializable]
public struct InventoryItems
{
    public string name;
}
```

### Added note:

The reason for this error is that the value of a public serializable member in monobehaviour is being read from the editor (inspector) overwriting any value being assigned to it prior to Awake.

I suggest either change the list accessor to internal, or make it a property, or keep it public but let inspector handle the initialization and adding the initial elements.

### Added another note:

According to Programmer and Uri Popov, your original code most certainly will work on unity 5.4 and later.

Comment: That's not his problem. I tested his code and it works for me. The reason must be somewhere else.

Comment: @UriPopov At one time, it **was**. Bijan, it would be good to mention that this happens with older version of Unity. I don't remember which version they fixed the `List` initialization problem but you can't find this problem in 5.4 and above.

Comment: First I would set the list private so there would not be somewhere a line resetting the list.

Comment: @Programmer that makes sense. I'm using 5.5. Disregard my previous comment this answer should fix his problem.

Comment: @Programmer I don't know about the unity update but initializing a public member in class body just does not make sense in unity.

Comment: `InventoryItems` does not inherit from `MonoBehaviour`. Some don't know this but what you just said applies only to most(90%) Unity API classes or structs. OP's `InventoryItems` struct is not a Unity API and does not inherit from `MonoBehaviour` so the code is fine. It works for @UriPopov. It works on my computer too so this is a Unity version issue.

Comment: @Programmer I see. Thanks for the info:-)